# Show that if $A$ is pseudo-ring and $\forall x,y \in A,\ xy=yx \text{ or } xy=-yx$ therefore $A$ is commutative or anti-commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $A$ be a pseudo-ring (ring without the existence of a multiplicative identity) and suppose $\forall x,y \in A,\ xy=yx \text{ or } xy=-yx$. Show that $A$ is commutative or anti-commutative ($\forall x,y \in A, \ xy=-yx$).

By posting this exercise, I am looking for different approches to this problem.

What I've done so far (draft):

We want to show that
$$
(\forall x,y \in A,\ xy=yx) \text{ or } (\forall x,y \in A,\ xy=-yx)
$$
So suppose that there exists $x_0,y_0 \in A$ such that $x_0y_0\neq -y_0x_0$. We have to show that $A$ is commutative to get the result. I don't see any obvious way to do so, so let suppose there exists $x_1,y_1 \in A$ such that $x_1 y_1 \neq y_1 x_1$. So we have $x_1 y_1 = -y_1 x_1$.
I'm stuck here.

Reference: Exercise 3.4 in *Exercices de mathématiques: oraux X-ENS (Algèbre I)*, by Francinou, Gianella, and Nicolas.

Comment: What is a pseudo-ring? What does it mean for a pseudo-ring to be anti-commutative?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've edited the post...

Comment: @Michelle How does what you wrote after "$A$ is a pseudo-ring so..." follow from not being a pseudo ring?  That does not look like the negation of having an identity.  I would guess you are overcomplicating this point anyhow. It is probably meant to include the case of a ring with identity too.

Comment: @rschwieb Indeed, I just realized that a ring is a pseudo-ring... I thought this meant that there was no identity element for $\times$... I was over focused on that. I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: as suggested by Qiaochu Yuan, I’m making explicit the lemma I’ll be using throughout the proof.

**Lemma**: let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ be two subgroups with $G=H \cup K$. Then $G=H$ or $G=K$.

*Proof*: Assume that the conclusion is false. Then there are $x \in G \backslash H, y \in G\backslash K$, so $x \in K,y \in H$. Then $xy$ is in $H$ or $K$. But if $xy \in H$, as $y \in H$, then $x =(xy)y^{-1}\in H$, a contradiction. Same if $xy \in K$, QED.

---

Let $x \in A$. Consider $C_x=\{y \in A,\, xy=yx\}$, and $S_x=\{y \in A,\, xy=-yx\}$. According to the hypothesis, $A=C_x \cup A_x$, and $C_x,S_x$ are additive subgroups of $A$, so $C_x=A$ or $S_x=A$.

Let $C$ be the set of $x$ with $C_x=A$ (aka the “center” of $A$) and $S$ the set of $x \in A$ with $S_x=A$. We just showed that $A=S \cup C$, and one easily checks that $C,S$ are additive subgroups of $A$. Therefore $C=A$ or $S=A$, QED.

Comment: +1: Reminds me of how I solved another group theory problem long ago: suppose $G$ is a group in which any set of three elements contains a pair that commutes. Prove $G$ is abelian.

Comment: I don’t quite understand how you conclude that $C_x = A$ or $S_x = A$. It looks like you’re referencing some fact about an abelian group not being the union of two proper subgroups and I guess I believe that but it seems worth saying a bit more explicitly.